# Scroll con Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola en este código que estoy haciendo como práctica me da un error, el codigo es :

```
    #----------cuadros a rellenar-----------
miFrame=Frame(root)
miFrame.pack()

miId=StringVar()
minombre=StringVar()
miPasword=StringVar()
miApellido=StringVar()
miDireccion=StringVar()
miComentarios=StringVar()


cuadroID=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=miId)
cuadroID.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
cuadroID.config(bg="green")

cuadroNombre=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=minombre)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
cuadroNombre.config(fg="red",justify="right")

cuadroPasword=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=miPasword)
cuadroPasword.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
cuadroPasword.config(show="*")

cuadroApellido=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=miApellido)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

cuadroDirección=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=miDireccion)
cuadroDirección.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)

cuadroComentarios=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=miComentarios)
cuadroComentarios.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
scrolVert=Scrollbar(miFrame, command=cuadroComentarios.yview)
scrolVert.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky="nsew")
cuadroComentarios.config(yscrollcommand=scrolVert.set)
```

El error que me da en Visual Studio Code es el siguiente:

> File "c:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\ejemplos\Python\PracticaGuiada_1\practica_mia.py",
>   line 112, in 
>       scrolVert=Scrollbar(miFrame, command=cuadroComentarios.yview) AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'yview'

Comment: Ya encontre una posible solucción o al menos que funciona el

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución o al menos que me funcione el código:

```
cuadroComentarios=Entry(miFrame,textvariable=miComentarios)
```

Cambiar `Entry` por `Text`:

```
cuadroComentarios=Text(miFrame,textvariable=miComentarios)
```